# How to determine if there are numbers in a string using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, count, numbers

I am needing to check how many emails have a number at the beginning of the email. For example, we emails like 11dataguy@email.com, 32emailfake@yahoo.com. If their are numbers before the emails, like in this example, I am needing to COUNT them. How would I do that?

So far my query is

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email)    
 FROM table    
WHERE email LIKE '%%.com'
```

That returns ALL values though, and I am specifically needing emails that start with a number.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: you need to count how many emails start with a number?  or you need to count how many numbers each email starts with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to count how many emails start with a number, you can simply use `regexp`

```
select count(*) 
from t
where email regexp '^[0-9]'
```

Comment: This worked! I have never heard of regexp. What if I wanted to know if it started with a letter prior to the domain? So if an email said tgmail.com, could I use regexp for letters as well?

Comment: [Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) are incredibly powerful and can accomodate just about any pattern you care to recognise.